# Can Regular Expression Capture Groups Be Modular or Variable?

Tags: regex, perl, regex-group

Can a regular expression capture group be made variable?

Can regex captures be made modular so that they can be reused throughout a more complete regex?

Can you simplify a regex that has many captures of the same format?

Answer (score 1):

There are some tricks you can use to make it modular.

You can make reusable patterns with `qr//`.  This operator compiles a regular expression and returns it such that it can be saved to a variable.  Capturing parenthesis are no different than any other regex term.

Those regex variables can be placed into larger regexes as if you had typed them out fully.  A variable can also be plain text which will be compiled into the regex when it is run.  This allows you to use the same code for several matching tasks.  It makes your logic flow simpler and easier to understand and debug.

```perl
$string = "AM[740];FM[89.5];SW[200]";

$bracket_contents = qr/\[([^\]]*)\]/;

$thing = "AM";
$am_value = $string =~ m/\b$thing$bracket_contents/ ? $1 : undef;

$thing = "SW";
($sw_value) = $string =~ m/\b$thing$bracket_contents/;
```